# Differentiating multiple products/quotients

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function

$$y(x) = \frac{u’(x)}{u(x)r(x)}$$

I want to differentiate this function to find $y’(x)$  in terms of $u’(x)$, $u(x)$, $r(x)$.

I am trying to decide whether to use the product or quotient rule but I have never seen a situation where there were three different functions of x all involved at the same time.

Any suggestions please on what approach I should take?

Thanks

Comment: You have a fraction so first imply quotient rule. and note that when you are doing this , you need product rule to find derivative of denominator.

Comment: I tend to prefer using the product rule rather than the quotient rule because I tend to forget the formula for the quotient rule, but it comes out naturally from the product rule. The product rule extends naturally to multiple factors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#A_product_of_more_than_two_factors

Answer (score 1):

$(ln(u(x))^`=\frac{u’(x)}{u(x)} $

$y(x) = \frac{u’(x)}{u(x)r(x)}=\frac{d\ln u}{dx} \frac1{r(x)} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d^2(\ln u)}{dx^2}\frac1{r(x)}+\frac{d\ln u}{dx}\frac{-r^`(x)}{r(x)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{u'\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)r\left(x\right)}\right)$$
Using the product rule with $\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$ and $\frac{1}{r(x)}$ gives
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{u'\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)}\right)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)}\right)+\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)}\right)\right)\left(\frac{u'\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)}\right)$$
Now you can differentiate $\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$ using the quotient rule to get
$$\frac{\left(u''\left(x\right)\right)\left(u\left(x\right)\right)-\left(u'\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}{\left(u\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)}\right)+\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)}\right)\right)\left(\frac{u'\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)}\right)$$

You could use the quotient rule for $\frac{1}{r(x)}$, but I think it's easier to use the chain rule. The derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, so using the chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)}\right)=-\frac{r'\left(x\right)}{\left(r\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}$.

Substituting this into what we had earlier gives
$$\frac{u''\left(x\right)\left(u\left(x\right)\right)-\left(u'\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}{\left(u\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)}\right)-\frac{r'\left(x\right)}{\left(r\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{u'\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)u\left(x\right)}\left(\frac{\left(u''\left(x\right)\left(u\left(x\right)\right)-\left(u'\left(x\right)\right)^{2}\right)}{u\left(x\right)}-\frac{r'\left(x\right)u'\left(x\right)}{r\left(x\right)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)u\left(x\right)}\left(\frac{u''\left(x\right)u\left(x\right)r\left(x\right)-\left(u'\left(x\right)\right)^{2}r\left(x\right)-r'\left(x\right)u'\left(x\right)u\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)r\left(x\right)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{r\left(x\right)u\left(x\right)}\left(u''\left(x\right)+\frac{-\left(u'\left(x\right)\right)^{2}r\left(x\right)-r'\left(x\right)u'\left(x\right)u\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)r\left(x\right)}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any of them but logarithmic differentiation instead
$$y(x) = \frac{u’(x)}{u(x)r(x)}\implies \log(y(x))=\log(u'(x))-\log(u(x))-\log(r(x))$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}=\frac{u''(x)}{u'(x)}-\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}-\frac{r'(x)}{r(x)}$$
$$y'(x)=y(x) \times\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$$ and simplify.